# Почему не помещаются кнопки в ряд?

Tags: java, button, jframe

Я создаю окошко шириной 195 и 4 кнопки в нём, шириной 41, а расстояние между кнопками 5. То есть общая ширина компонентов и промежутков 189, и они должны поместиться в одном ряду, но не помещаются, что я делаю не так?
На скриншоте видно, что окно слишком узкое, это значит, я где-то неправильно указываю расстояние?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame
{
    Container container = getContentPane();
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[4];
    FlowLayout layout1 = new FlowLayout(0, 5, 5);
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestFrame();
    }
    
    TestFrame()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(200, 200, 190, 243);
        
        container.setLayout(layout1);
        
        for (JButton b : buttons)
        {
            b = new JButton("b");
            b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(41, 26));
            container.add(b);
        }
        
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Я вижу 190, а не 195

Comment: Вы не учитываете отступы от краев экрана

Comment: Какие отступы от краёв экрана я не учитываю? Это такие же 5 пикселей, как и  между кнопками 5*5 + 41*4 = 189, но выставленного размера на 190 явно не хватает, даже на скриншоте видно, что кнопки не поместились бы. Или там должны быть какие-то еще отступы?